# Data Creating and occupying a blank space in layout, but cannot see it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The Data from the web service is received properly, I got it checked by printing all the value in Log, so obviously there is no error from my back-end service. The data is also occupying blank space as per the array size of my list in layout, but i cannot see the data, only white screen with the TextView. There are **no errors in the LogCat**. I don't know what i did wrong, little help would be appreciated. Thanks

This is my **MainActivity** which has **AsyncTask** to fetch the Data.

```
 swaop=(SwipeRefreshLayout)contentview.findViewById(R.id.layout_offerproducts);
    rvofferproducts = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_offerproducts);

    oparraylist = new ArrayList<B_OfferProducts>();

    opadapter = new adapter_offerproducts(getApplicationContext(), oparraylist);

    final RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    rvofferproducts.setLayoutManager(manager);
    rvofferproducts.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    rvofferproducts.setAdapter(opadapter);

    isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();

    if(isConnected)
    {
        new loadallofferproducts().execute();
    }
       //ASYNC TASK
    public class loadallofferproducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OfferID", OfferID));

        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_offerproducts, "POST", params);

        try {
            int success = jsonObject.getInt("success");

            if(success == 1)
            {
                ophasharraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                offerproductsarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("offerproducts");

                for(int i = 0; i < offerproductsarray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject opobj =offerproductsarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String ProductId = opobj.getString("ProductID");
                    String ProductName = opobj.getString("ProductName");
                    String ProductPrice = "₹ " + opobj.getString("ProductPrice");
                    String ProductDP = "₹ " +opobj.getString("ProductDiscountP");
                    String ProductURL = opobj.getString("ProductPicURL");
                    String ProductDescription = opobj.getString("ProductDescription");

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                   B_OfferProducts b_offerProducts = new B_OfferProducts();

                    map.put("ProductID", ProductId);
                    map.put("ProductName", ProductName);
                    map.put("ProductPrice", ProductPrice);
                    map.put("ProductDiscountP", ProductDP);
                    map.put("ProductPicURL",ProductURL);
                    map.put("ProductDescription", ProductDescription);

                    ophasharraylist.add(map);

                    b_offerProducts.setProductPicURL(ophasharraylist.get(i).get("ProductPicURL").trim());
                    b_offerProducts.setProductName(ophasharraylist.get(i).get("ProductName").trim());
                    b_offerProducts.setProductPrice(ophasharraylist.get(i).get("ProductPrice").trim());
                    b_offerProducts.setProductDiscountP(ophasharraylist.get(i).get("ProductDiscountP").trim());
                    b_offerProducts.setProductDescription(ophasharraylist.get(i).get("ProductDescription").trim());

                    Log.d("OfferProducts",b_offerProducts.getProductName());
                    oparraylist.add(b_offerProducts);

                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        opadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

This is **My Adapter** class.

```
public class adapter_offerproducts extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter_offerproducts.MyViewHolder>{

private List<B_OfferProducts> offerproductlist;
Context mcontext;

public class MyViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView pname, pprice, pdpricce, pdescription;
    public ImageView pimg;

    public MyViewHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);

        pname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rv_op_pname);
        pprice = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rv_op_pprice);
        pdpricce = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rv_op_pdprice);
        pdescription = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rv_op_pdescription);

        pimg = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.rv_op_img);
    }
}

public adapter_offerproducts(Context context, List<B_OfferProducts> oplist )
{
    mcontext = context;
    this.offerproductlist = oplist;
}

public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_container_offerproducts,parent,false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemview);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

   B_OfferProducts b_offerProducts = new B_OfferProducts();
    Picasso.get()
            .load(b_offerProducts.getProductPicURL())
            .into(holder.pimg);

    holder.pname.setText(b_offerProducts.getProductName());
    holder.pprice.setText(b_offerProducts.getProductPrice());
    holder.pdpricce.setText(b_offerProducts.getProductDiscountP());
    holder.pdescription.setText(b_offerProducts.getProductDescription());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return offerproductlist.size();
  }
}
```

This is **My Container** for RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/rv_op_img"
    android:contentDescription="ProductImage"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rv_op_pname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rv_op_img"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rv_op_pprice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rv_op_img"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="56dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rv_op_pdprice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rv_op_img"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="96dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rv_op_pdescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rv_op_img"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="131dp" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is **My Activity Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/layout_offerproducts"
  tools:context="com.test.OfferProducts">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rv_offerproducts">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Blah This IS TEXT" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting TextView `android:layout_height` to fixed  value?

Comment: @Gotiasits, Yes i have tried but still same.. Occupying white space but cannot see data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should be getting your `B_OfferProducts` from list passed to adapter, that is from List `offerproductlist`, instead of creating an object every time.

Regardless of what you put in the constructor of `B_OfferProducts` class, your items will not be bind to the list, which is probably the reason why data is not loading correctly. These objects created will live only inside ViewHolder.

This means that you should replace

```
B_OfferProducts b_offerProducts = new B_OfferProducts();
```

in `onBindViewHolder()` with getting the object relevant to the current postion in the list, so like this:

```
B_OfferProducts b_offerProducts = offerproductlist.get(position)
```

I hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, been stuck in this like for 2 days. Thank you very much for your time and help.